# PmWiki disable public edit

Tags: php, html, wiki, pmwiki

I recently Installed PmWiki and want to make a Site like this: http://medesign.seas.upenn.edu/index.php

But PmWiki is a wiki software so everyone have access to edit pages - I dont want to have this.

But I dont know how to make a page like my example, I found out that AuthUser is doing something like athorization, but I dont know how to setup it correctly, just for lonely pages with:

- Restrict reading the SiteAdmin/AuthUser page to the @admins group.
- Go to http://yourwiki.com/pmwiki.php?n=SiteAdmin/AuthUser&action=attr then put "@admins" in the "read" field''.
- Now only the actual administrator can read the page (no one is in the @admins group at this time, and AuthUser is not turned on yet).
- It will ask for a password. Use the one (example: itsmytemporarysecret) from the previous step.

So anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps provided will prevent access to `http://yourwiki.com/pmwiki.php?n=SiteAdmin/AuthUser` page only, not for other pages. Also, it will prevent reading instead of editing, since you have set `@admins` in `read` field.

[Here](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/AuthUser) is a complete guide on how to activate AuthUser.

Basically, you have to add these two lines in the end of local/config.php:
`include_once("$FarmD/scripts/authuser.php");
$DefaultPasswords['edit'] = array('@admins', 'id:USERNAME_1,USERNAME_2');`

Just make sure to change `USERNAME_1,USERNAME_2`to the users allowed to edit. So they doesn't need to be admins to edit a page.

Another method is to set a [site wide password](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/PasswordsAdmin#settingsitewidepasswords), so anyone who knows it can edit. 
To do this, add the following line to the end of local/config.php:
`$DefaultPasswords['edit'] = crypt('edit_password');`